# Distinguishing Two Topological Spaces, Each a Union of $\mathbb{S}^1$ and a Line

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Currently working on a problem to review for my topology final.

> Let $\mathbb{S}^1$ be the unit circle $\{(x, y, 0) : x^2 + y^2 = 1\} \subset \mathbb{R}^3$. Let $M = \{(0,0,z) : z \in \mathbb{R}\}$ and $N = \{(2,0,z) : z \in \mathbb{R}^3\}$. Show that there does not exist a homeomorphism $h: \mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ such that $h(\mathbb{S}^1 \cup M) = \mathbb{S}^1 \cup N$.

Intuitively, this makes sense. I often think of lines as circles with infinite radii, so from this perspective one space consists of interlinked circles and one doesn't. But this is imprecise. I should be able to do is prove that there actually does not exist a homeomorphism in $\mathbb{R}^3$ between the two spaces. This is where I am getting stuck. I can't seem to reach a contradiction by assuming there $does$ exist such a homeomorphism in $\mathbb{R}^3$. Any suggestions?

Comment: If you consider the spaces themselves, the two are homeomorphic. I suspect the $\not\cong$ here takes the ambient space into account, something like "there doesn't exist a homeomorphism $\mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{R}^3$ that maps $M$ to $N$".

Comment: Yes you are right, I should have been more careful in transcribing the problem. I will make that more precise.

Comment: @DanielFischer: I guess you mean the two are inequivalent as knots.

Comment: I think computing the fundamental group of the complement of each of the respective spaces can show that the two spaces are not equivalent as knots.

Comment: We did not go into knot theory in my course, so I don't think I can use that.

Comment: @A.E As Daniel Fischer says, the spaces *are* homeomorphic. Can you fix the question?

Comment: Alright, I've fixed it. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**: ${\bf R^3}\setminus (\mathbb{S}^1 \cup M)$ deformation retracts onto a torus with the circle at its core, and the fundamental group of ${\bf R^3}\setminus (\mathbb{S}^1 \cup N)$ is nonabelian by Van Kampen's theorem.

Comment: Can you elaborate on your first point?

Comment: @A.E: Consider the orthogonal projection onto the torus.

Comment: But how could I show that no homeomorphism from $\mathbb{R}^3$ to $\mathbb{R}^3$ exists?

Comment: @A.E: if it existed, it would also take the complement of one set to the complement of the other, but it can't do that if they have distinct fundamental groups...